# Is Pkg.clone obsolete?

Tags: package, installation, julia, clone

I have attempted to install several packages listed at JuliaObserver which are not in the Julia registry but instead are to be downloaded from github. The instructions at JuliaObserver look like this but depending on the particular repository:

`Pkg.clone("https://github.com/JuliaDataReaders/DataReaders.jl.git")`

These attempts all fail with "UndefVarError: clone not defined".

Answer (score 7):

Yes, `Pkg.clone` is part of the old API. The new API is documented here https://julialang.github.io/Pkg.jl/v1/api.html
In particular, you get a similar behaviour by

```
using Pkg
pkg"add <URL or package name>" # If you want to install the package
pkg"dev <URL or package name>" # If you want to develop the package
```

If the package is registered, you can provide the package name above. If not, you need to provide the full URL to the repo

Comment: I didn't find the form that you suggest on the linked page. Instead, I found this `Pkg.add(PackageSpec(url="https://github.com/JuliaLang/Example.jl", rev="master"))`. Is that what you meant?

Comment: The form I wrote uses the `pkg` string macro, which lets you input commands as if you were in the Pkg REPL mode. It allows for sparser syntax compared to the `PackageSpec` version.

Comment: Your method results in "could not find project file in package at "https://github.com/JuliaLang/Example.jl"..." My method didn't complain but after "using DataReaders" it errors with "Run `import Pkg; Pkg.add("DataReaders")`" after which I get "DataReaders (not found in project, manifest or registry)" Sigh. I guess this is yet another unmaintained Julia package. So disappointed.

Comment: `julia> pkg"add https://github.com/JuliaLang/Example.jl"` works for me. DataReaders.jl has not been updated in a very long time and does appear to be abandoned.

Comment: Thanks Fredrik. Still, `pkg"add https://github.com/JuliaDataReaders/DataReaders.jl.git"` causes `ERROR: could not find project file in package at...blabla`. I believe this package needs some maintenance to work with Julia 1+.

Comment: Yes, that package does not use the new Project.toml file, instead it uses the old REQUIRE file, which is no longer supported. If it has not been updated to use the Project.toml file it's unlikely to work under julia v1.x without significant attention.